# Strange javax.el.propertynotfoundexception

Tags: jakarta-ee, propertynotfoundexception

I'm trying to develop an application under glassfish-3.1.2. I've the following Groups entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = Groups.FIND_BY_ID, query="SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = Groups.FIND_BY_NAME, query="SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.group_name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = Groups.FIND_ALL, query="SELECT g FROM Groups g ORDER BY g.group_name")})

public class Groups implements Serializable {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Groups.findAll";
    public static final String FIND_BY_ID = "Groups.findById";
    public static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "Groups.findByName";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String group_name;
    private String group_desc;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "UsersGroups")
    private List<Users> user;
    /* Follow setters and getters
```

and Firmware entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "findById", query="SELECT f FROM Firmware f WHERE f.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "findByType", query="SELECT f FROM Firmware f WHERE f.type = "type"),
@NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Firmware f ORDER BY f.type")})
public class Firmware implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String type; 
    /* Follow getters and setters */
```

and the following Beans

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean  
public class GroupsEJB {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

 public Groups persist(Groups group) {
    em.persist(group);
    return group;
}

 public Groups getById(Long id) {
    TypedQuery<Groups> query = em.createNamedQuery("findById",   Groups.class).setParameter("id", id);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}

public List<Groups> getAllGroups() {
    TypedQuery<Groups> query = em.createNamedQuery("findAll", Groups.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<Groups> getByName(String name) {
    TypedQuery<Groups> query = em.createNamedQuery("findByName", Groups.class).setParameter("group_name", name);
    return query.getResultList();
}
}


@Stateless
@LocalBean                                                                          
public class FirmwareEJB {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of FirmwareEJB
 */
public FirmwareEJB() {
}
  public Firmware persist(Firmware firmware) {
    em.persist(firmware);
    return firmware;
}

public List<Firmware> getAllFirmware() {
    TypedQuery<Firmware> query = em.createNamedQuery("findAll", Firmware.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<Firmware> getByType(String type) {
    TypedQuery<Firmware> query = em.createNamedQuery("findByType", Firmware.class).setParameter("type", type);
    return query.getResultList();
}
 public Firmware getById(Long id) {
    TypedQuery<Firmware> query = em.createNamedQuery("findById", Firmware.class).setParameter("id", id);
    return query.getSingleResult();
    //Firmware f = em.find(Firmware.class, id);
    //return f;
}        
}
```

and the following controllers

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class GroupsController {

@EJB
private GroupsEJB groupsEJB;

private Groups group = new Groups();
private List<Groups> groupsList = new ArrayList<Groups>();


/**
 * Creates a new instance of GroupsController
 */
public GroupsController() {
}

public String createGroup() {
    return "createGroup.xhtml";
}

public String saveGroup() {

    group = groupsEJB.persist(group);
    groupsList = groupsEJB.getAllGroups();
    return "listGroups.xhtml";
}

public String listGroups() {
    groupsList = groupsEJB.getAllGroups();
    return "listGroups.xhtml";
}

public Groups getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Groups group) {
    this.group = group;
}

public List<Groups> getGroupsList() {
    return groupsList;
}

public void setGroupsList(List<Groups> groupsList) {
    this.groupsList = groupsList;
}



@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FirmwareController {

@EJB
private FirmwareEJB firmwareEJB;
private Firmware firmware = new Firmware();
private List<Firmware> firmwareList = new ArrayList<Firmware>();

/**
 * Creates a new instance of FirmwareController
 */
public FirmwareController() {
}

public String newFirmware() {
    return "newFirmware.xhtml";
}

public String saveFirmware() {
    List type = firmwareEJB.getByType(firmware.getType());
    if (!type.isEmpty()) {
        addMessage("Firmware already exist.");
        return "newFirmware.xhtml";
    }
    firmware = firmwareEJB.persist(firmware);
    firmwareList = firmwareEJB.getAllFirmware();
    return "listFirmware.xhtml";
}

public String listFirmware() {
    firmwareList = firmwareEJB.getAllFirmware();
    return "listFirmware.xhtml";

}

public String searchFirmware() {
    return "searchFirmware.xhtml";
}

public String searchFirmwareById() {
    Long id = firmware.getId();
    Firmware f = firmwareEJB.getById(id);
    addMessage("Firmware: " + f.getType());
    return "searchFirmware.xhtml";
}

public List<Firmware> getFirmwareList() {
    return firmwareList;
}

public void setFirmwareList(List<Firmware> firmwareList) {
    this.firmwareList = firmwareList;
}

public Firmware getFirmware() {
    return firmware;
}

public void setFirmware(Firmware firmware) {
    this.firmware = firmware;
}
```

So, when I use the following jsf:

```
 <ui:composition template="./base.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:dataTable value="${groupsController.groupsList}" var="g" >

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Group Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="${g.group_name}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Group Description" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="${g.group_desc}" />
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
```

to show the list of groups, I obtain

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /listGroups.xhtml @25,65 value="${g.group_name}": The class 'entities.Firmware' does not have the property 'group_name'.
```

I rebuild, rewrite, without solution. I'm unable to find a solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To see the getters and setters would be nice. Just a shot in the dark: Using Underscores in  Properties does not comply to the Java Bean cnovention. I am sure this could also be the source of your problem. I am sure if you fiddle with the casing you could  work it out. I would strongly suggest though that you rename the property to groupName and have setGroupName and getGroupName, and use g.groupName as the expression.

Comment: I changed the names but I have the same result:                 /listGroups.xhtml @25,64 value="${g.groupName}": The class 'entities.Firmware' does not have the property 'groupName'.

Comment: Oh I missed this, I have no idea why the JSF is looking inside the Firmware class. My first suggestions was, that your controller is linked up incorrectly, but this is bogus, as the firmware controller has no groupsList property.  Are you sure you have the correct JSF code? Double check you are looking in the proper XHTML file and see what line 25, column 65 points to.